# update cordova version7.1.0 cordova add platform ios failed

Tags: node.js, cordova

Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-ios@~4.4.0
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! Darwin 16.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.4.1_1/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "cordova-ios@~4.4.0" "--save"
npm ERR! node v5.4.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.3
npm ERR! code EGAUGE

npm ERR! Missing template value "progressbar"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
npm WARN helloworld@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN In cordova-ios@4.4.0 replacing bundled version of xcode with xcode@0.9.3
npm ERR! Darwin 16.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.4.1_1/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "cordova-ios@~4.4.0" "--save"
npm ERR! node v5.4.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.3

Answer (score 0):

update cordova version7.1.0 cordova add platform ios failed

Answer (score 0):

Please try to update cordova as latest version.

```
npm install -g cordova
```

and it will add cordova-ios@4.5.0 and it will work fine.